# create your own session id in struts2 or j2ee app

Tags: session, struts2, sessionid

I have an app using Struts2 jsp and java..sessionid is created by container.I want to create my own session id and set to that particular session...just want to overwrite.I have aslo created a filter. session id.any clue

something like

session.setSessionId()

thanks..

Comment: What is your use case? What are you trying to do, and why?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [CookieInterceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/CookieInterceptor.html) which can implement [CookiesAware](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.2/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/CookiesAware.html) and then intercept the call to set your own sessionId.

Edit:

Just realized CookieInterceptor doesnt allow you to set a cookie, so I did something like this

In my execute method of my `Action` I did this:

```
public String execute() {
        String jSessionId = null;
        for (Cookie c : httpServletRequest.getCookies()) {
            if (c.getName().equals("JSESSIONID"))
                jSessionId = c.getValue();
        }
        System.out.println("Value Found In Request = " + jSessionId);
        jSessionId = "TestingOverrideOfJSessionId";
        Cookie myCookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", jSessionId);
        myCookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365); // Make the cookie last a year
        httpServletResponse.addCookie(myCookie);

        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Result

[image: SessionId Override]

Comment: will you pls give some code snippet? By the way session id is generated by Container not by cookies....Pls elaborate

Comment: I dont have time right now, but I will check this one from home.

Comment: thanks....one thing more how can we detect that same url in another tab opened so that i can session out first one.

Comment: thats tricky, you will have to store jSession id somewhere, so if user opens another tab and opens the same url you will get jSession id, check if this id is already in use, if yes then logoout the other session. But you cannot do this blindly, you need to see which action user is trying to invoke, as not for all actions you can do this. This is a big functionality in its own